# How to select a specific tr based on attribute value

Tags: jquery

i got this table html:

```
<table id="mytable">
<thead>
<tr role="row">
<th aria-controls="dog"></th>
<th aria-controls="cat"></th>
<th aria-controls="fish"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

and i want to select the th where the attribute is "dog".

i try this :

```
$("th").attr("aria-controls"="dog");
```

what is a god way to do it?
if i can i avoid looping on all the tr it will be even better.

thanks :)

Comment: You don't try this, because it's a syntax error. You just google first.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can select elements by what an attribute's value is equal to like this:

```
var element = $('th[aria-controls="dog"]')
```

More info on attribute equals selector here: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

As a side note the `th` is not even necessary or the attribute's value to test against. You can simply select all elements with that attribute regardless of its value too like this:

```
var element = $('[aria-controls]')
```

There are many ways of using this selector. You can even find elements with that attribute that start, end or contain the value.

Starts with: `var element = $('[aria-controls|="dog"]')` ex: dogggg

Ends with: `var element = $('[aria-controls$="dog"]')` ex: adog

Contains: `var element = $('[aria-controls*="dog"]')` ex: bdogb

Not equal: `var element = $('[aria-controls!="dog"]')` ex: cat

More info on attribute selectors in general here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: The question is just about finding the link to the docs by googling the question name, really answering it?..

Comment: Sure, i see what you mean. But they did show some code of what they attempted so was just helping.

Comment: They did show no code, just a wild guess, I have no idea why did OP even include it in their code. But even if it's considered code - this question is not a question. It's just a specific article of documentation, which OP just didn't read.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have with:

```
$("th").attr("aria-controls"="dog");
```

Is primarily that it's a syntax error (`Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`); this is because there are two uses for the `attr()` method, getting or setting a value.

If you provide *one* argument it's a getter, and returns the value of the given attribute:

```
$('th').attr('aria-controls');
```

Will then return the value of the `aria-controls` attribute from the first/only element returnd by the `$('th')` collection of elements.

To *set* an attribute to a given value:

```
$('th').attr('aria-controls', 'aria-controls new value');
```

Which will set the attribute-value of the `aria-controls` attribute to the supplied value of `'aria-controls new value'` (the second argument to the method).

You'll note that *neither* of these approaches uses the assignment (`=`) operator.

To find an element via its given attribute, and attribute-value, you need to use the attribute-equals (`[attribute=attribute-value]`) selector syntax from CSS:

```
$('th[aria-controls=dog]');
```

Comment: What OP's doing is essentially trying to assign constant to constant in the function arguments, see it? Basically OP just didn't read about 1) functions 2) assignments; two basic things. Trying to explain it there? Any reason or aim?

Comment: I was simply trying to provide a specific answer to the OP's question despite closing it as a duplicate of another; this way hopefully s/he may learn something about why their own attempt failed *and* to search in future before asking a question.

Comment: As for searching in future - how does providing an answer help to search in future? The next time OP asks another similar question, gets the easy answer and doesn't even notice it's a dupe.

Comment: The provision of an answer specific to his/her problem was my choice - I don't feel the need to justify that to you - as for learning to search, that's an assumption based on the existence of a duplicate question, a question *this* question was closed as a duplicate-of within ten minutes. Maybe s/he will learn, maybe s/he won't. I don't see the loss of around two minutes as a significant waste, even if it was wholly wasted.